# Bug Navigation Drawer combinado con viewpager y tabs

Tags: android-studio, navigation-drawer

he estado implementando con la plantilla e NavigationDrawer activity mi aplicación. En uno de los fragmentos del menu he implementado una pantalla deslizante (tabs) la cual carga bien y tiene su funcionalidad. Esta pantalla al ser el main del navigation drawer va perfecto al abrir la aplicación, pero si vuelvo a abrir el fragmento que contiene el deslizante este ya no carga el contenido. Lo mismo pasa si desde cualquier otro fragment del menu le doy al botón hacia atras del movil. hay que destacar que esto solo ocurre con el fragment que tiene el tabs.
El fragmento que almacena los otros fragmentos

```
private AppBarLayout appBar;
private TabLayout pestanas;
private ViewPager viewPager;


public PopularesFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_populares, container, false);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        insertarTabs();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        poblarViewPager(viewPager);
        pestanas.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
    //Cambiar titulo toolbar
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).cargarTituloToolBar("- POPULARES");

    return view;
}

private void insertarTabs() {
    appBar = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
    pestanas = new TabLayout(getActivity());
    pestanas.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_base));
    pestanas.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.naranja_oscuro));
    pestanas.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.naranja_oscuro));
    pestanas.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(10);
    appBar.addView(pestanas);
}

private void poblarViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    AdaptadorSecciones adapter = new AdaptadorSecciones(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new PopularesFragmentIntern(), "Dentro");
    adapter.addFragment(new PopularesFragmentExtern(), "final");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    appBar.removeView(pestanas);
}
public class AdaptadorSecciones extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentos = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> titulosFragmentos = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdaptadorSecciones(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentos.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentos.add(fragment);
        titulosFragmentos.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titulosFragmentos.get(position);
    }
}
```

El xml que almacena los fragments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

El mainactivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
            // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
            mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                    R.id.nav_populares, R.id.nav_milista, R.id.nav_viendo, R.id.nav_terminados, R.id.nav_noticias,R.id.nav_generos,R.id.nav_detalle)
                    .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                    .build();
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}
```

El xml del mainactivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/color_base"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/color_iconos"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_iconos"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

El appbar_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AnimePosit.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:buttonGravity="top"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AnimePosit.PopupOverlay"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/letras_final"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lupa"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/texto_nobre_pantalla"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/comentar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/compartir"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic__comentar"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,VectorDrawableCompat"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/compartir"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lupa"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic__compartir"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,VectorDrawableCompat"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/buscador"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/fondo_gris_redondo"
                    android:hint="BUSCAR"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/texto_mediano"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_base"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/color_base"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible">
                </EditText>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lupa"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic__lupa"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,VectorDrawableCompat"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Contentmain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Nav_header_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_base"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen_usuario"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre_usuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textSize="@dimen/texto_normal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_usuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textSize="@dimen/texto_pequeño"
        android:textColor="@color/color_iconos"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Y el código? Recuerda que para poder ayudarte necesitmos ver el código.

Comment: Lo acabo de añadir, básicamente tengo un NavigationDrawer_Activity (el por defecto que te crea android) al cual le he añadido el tabs en uno de sus destinos. He seguido este tutorial [enlace] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMdXpF-MKUo&t=1s

Comment: Para añadir un enlace debes poner primero los corchetes y luego los paréntesis [ejemplo (link -- recuerda que debes cerrarlos--

Comment: Bien, lo que veo a simple vista es que mediante un `if` preguntas si el `savedInstance` es `null` con eso cada vez que lo vuelvas a iniciar o vuelvas al mismo , no cargará nada. Ya que este saldra por el `else` porque dejó de ser nulo.

Comment: Si, en la versión que subí no lo había cambiado. si lo hago sin ninguna comprobación los fragmentos siguen sin cargarse

Comment: Si lo hago igual que en el enlace que he pasado solo va la primera vez ya que se carga ese fragment como pricipal, y luego ya no funciona de ninguna forma